# At which layer of TCP/IP does nf_hook - kernel works?

Tags: networking, network-programming, linux-device-driver, tcp

At which layer of TCP/IP does packet filtering works. I am writing a kernel module that has a nf_hook that will simply drop the packet based on the port - for example TCP or UDP. I want to know at what layer does the nf_hook works in TCP/IP stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Layer 3: Network layer**

More information on networking kernel can be found [here](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/kernel_flow).